# Understanding momentjs timezones

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I'm using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) in my project.

To get the current date and time in a given format I'm using this:

```
moment().format('ddd, D MMM HH:mm'); // Tue, 12 May 12:01
```

If I output this and view in my browser, I see *Tue, 12 May 12:01*. I'm currently in London which is UTC+1. If someone did the same from Florida, I assume they would see *Tue, 12 May 07:01* (UTC-4)?

**My question**

How can I make sure everyone views the UTC+1 time regardless of where they are in the world? I think the following would be the way to do it but am not sure.

```
moment().tz('Europe/London').format('ddd, D MMM HH:mm'); // Tue, 12 May 12:01
```

Hoping someone can explain.

Comment: Did you test it? Without knowing the api of momentjs, it looks reasonable. Did you try it in a browser?

Comment: I can only test in my own browser, which works as expected (I'm in London, England). But I can't test in a browser elsewhere in the world

Comment: You can change the timezone of your computer =)

Comment: Or of course, use a different timezone for testing, such as `America/New_York`.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that @Evert :(

Comment: It's different on every operating system, but I'm sure you can google "How to change timezone on Mac/Ubuntu/Windows/etc..."

Comment: I think @T.J.Crowder's idea might be easier :)

Comment: Fair enough, but the exercise might still be valuable ;) file under basic computer skills.

Comment: Sure, always worth knowing how to do these things; I'm going to look into it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should work. Here's an example showing the default time zone, Europe/London, and American/New_York:

```js
const now = new Date();

console.log("Default: " + moment(now).format("ddd, D MMM HH:mm z"));
console.log("Europe/London: " + moment(now).tz("Europe/London").format("ddd, D MMM HH:mm z"));
console.log("America/New_York: " + moment(now).tz("America/New_York").format("ddd, D MMM HH:mm z"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.38/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Running the code snippet, my 'default' time matches Europe/London (I assume that's because I'm in London?). So, someone running this from New York, the 'default' time would match America/New_York?